# Unexplainable MySQL composite key issue with .NET Application

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, vb.net

I am writing a .NET application that interact with MySQL database using ODBC connection. My application will create the database schema and tables on the database upon start up. However, I encountered a weird unexplainable case below:

First my application will create the following table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sample` (
`item_ID` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`item_No` int(11) NOT NULL,
`sample_col1` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`sample_col2` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`item_ID`, `item_No`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Populate the table with

```
INSERT INTO sample SET item_ID='abc', item_No=1, sample_col1='', sample_col2='';
INSERT INTO sample SET item_ID='abc', item_No=2, sample_col1='', sample_col2='';
```

Then I execute a SELECT query from within the .NET application using the following code:

```
Dim query As String
query = "SELECT item_ID, item_No, sample_col1, sample_col2 FROM sample"

Dim conn As New OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=localhost; port=3306;Database=test; User=dbuser;Password=dbpassword;Option=3;")
Dim cmd As New OdbcDataAdapter(query, conn)
Dim dt As New DataTable
cmd.FillSchema(dt, SchemaType.Source)
cmd.Fill(dt)
conn.Close()
```

The `cmd.Fill(dt)` line will throw an Exception: "Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints".

However if I modify the table creation query to:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sample` (
`item_ID` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`item_No` int(11) NOT NULL,
`sample_col1` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`sample_col2` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`item_No`,`item_ID`)  '--> Here Primary Key order is inverted
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The vb.net code works perfectly. Notice on the second creation query I inverted the order of the PRIMARY KEY creation. On the first example I put `item_ID` first while on the second example I put `item_No` first.

Does anyone has any clue why this is happening? Also is there any difference from the point of view of MySQL database between the first and second create query?

Any input will be appreciated. Thank you !

Comment: *On the first example I put item_ID first* I must be missing something.

Comment: You might want to edit the post to change the first example, and avoid confusion, cause both the create statements look similar.

Comment: Changed. Thank you for spotting it.

Comment: As I understand the composite primary key has to start with the most unique column. That is the reason the second sample works, as you have unique Item_NO

Comment: But I thought composite key should be viewed as a whole and in my application there is no such thing as 'most' unique because the next row of data always contains item_No 1, 2, 3. Having that means column `item_No` should be less unique than `item_ID`. Sample populated data would be: item_ID='abc' --> item_No=1, item_No=2, item_No=3. item_ID='efg' --> item_No=1, item_No=2, item_No=3. etc